# absolute positioned div not expanding in height

Tags: html, css

I am not sure why absolute position div is not expanding in height ( div.class1 )

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/209/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="space">
    </div>
    <div class="class1 hz">
      <div class="class2 class3">
        item2
      </div>
      <div class="class2 class3">
        item2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
.space {
  margin-top:80px;
}

.content {
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid transparent;
}

.hz {
  top:20%;
  margin:0 auto;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  display:inline-block;
}


.class1 {
  position: absolute;
  top:160px;
  width: 985px;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.class2 {
  width : 275px;
  height : 250px;
  margin-right:20px;
   border:1px solid red;
}

.class3 {
  width : 325px;
  height: 280px;
  margin-right:3px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Not exactly sure if this is what you want, but try adding "html,body{height:100%;} to your styles: http://jsfiddle.net/krrwM/

Comment: You didn't really explain what are you trying to do. This can help us help you.

Comment: try delete height: 100%; in class1

Comment: @JohanNordli....your suuggestion worked.

Answer (score 2):

Add `display:table;` to .class1

```
.class1 {
  position: absolute;
  display:table;
  top:160px;
  width: 985px;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/213/

Answer (score 0):

change position to relative and it will fit the height 100%

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AhmedAlaaElDin/z9Unk/212/

```
.class1 {
  position: relative;
  top:160px;
  width: 985px;
  height:100%;
  border:2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: so I still need to try this. Actually I need to do sticky footer. I ran into other issues. I will update the post soon.